# SWIFT: can't click on subview

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I create new subview

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menu") as! MenuViewController
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -150, self.view.frame.size.width, 150);
    mainView.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.view.layer.zPosition = 1
    controller.viewDidLoad()
```

then I add button on viewController

But I cant click on button...

I can select text which is under the my new controller (I add photos)

[image]

Comment: Why are you setting the `zPosition?` Adding it as a subview will automatically bring it to the front.

Comment: And why are you doing all those other things manually?

Comment: without zPosition not working:/

Answer (score 0):

Few things problematic with your code.

Firstly, you have no need as far as I can tell from the limited scope of your code, you have no need to be setting the layer's `zPosition` property to anything other than the default value of zero. By using `addSubview`, the view you're adding is automatically added to the top of all current subviews.

Secondly, essentially there's nothing wrong with creating frames programatically, however more often than not this will lead to issues on devices with different screen sizes. Also, as you're setting the view's width to be equal to that of another view, I recommend using autolayout which will automatically update the width should it change. It also allows you to create a responsive interface across all device screen sizes/size classes.

```
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -150, self.view.frame.size.width, 150);
```

Thirdly, there is no need to manually trigger the `controller.viewDidLoad()` as it's automatically called once its frame has been set.

Fourthly (!) you are setting the view's frame to be hidden off the top of the screen. I'm not sure this is the right functionality, but wanted to make sure that you were aware that by setting the `y` origin of the view to be equal to that of the frame, the bottom of the view will be aligned with the top of its superview.

Container view controllers are view controllers that contain other view controllers, allowing you to create more modular code, and separate views out into managed view controllers. This pattern should be used instead.

See https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/ for more info.

In the following code, I also perform a check to see if the `controller` variable is nil, which will prevent a crash when you try to force unwrap the controller and it's not of class `MenuViewController`. Understandably this is somewhat pedantic as you may be certain that the view controller being instantiated is the correct one, but it's always better to be safe than sorry.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menu") as?  MenuViewController {
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -150, self.view.frame.size.width, 150);
    // Frame may need to be modified to be made visible ^
    addChildViewController(controller)
    controller.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
    mainView.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.widMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

Comment: One small quibble: `viewDidLoad()` is called after the view loads, regardless of whether the view is onscreen. The call to `controller.view.frame` will cause `viewDidLoad()` to run, even before `controller.view` is added as a subview.

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes, you're right! I've updated the answer.